# Cordova android push notifications by OneSignal

Tags: android, cordova, notifications

I set up push notifications to Android by onesignal. On Android 4.2 comes all right . But Android 5.0 notifications are not displayed. Device correctly register but dont show notifications.
I just dont know in what way search additional information. What can be reason of that issue? Thank you

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: Can you get the logcat from the device by running `ddms` or `adb logcat`. Open your app then press the home button to background it, then send a notification and watch what is outputted in the logcat. Look for an GCM entries, warnings, or errors. You can also send the full logcat to support@onesignal.com and they can take a look at it.